# css and js work fine on other page except when i search any post using search bar for my custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

My css and js load on page source and work fine on sample page and single page but when i search any post via side bar my css and js for plugin does nothing

Image with css and js loading fine:

[image]

Image with css and js not working though it loads when checked through view_page_source:

[image]

```
function my_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style('style',plugins_url('/css/custom.css', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style('fontow',plugins_url('/css/font-awesome.min.css', __FILE__ ));



    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'),true,true);
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_url',array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );    
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );

function wpa_rating_ad($content) {
    global $post;
    $thePostID = $post->ID; 
        $star='
        <p>
            <div class="rating">
                <legend>Please rate:</legend>
                <input type="radio" id="star5-'.$thePostID.'"  name="rating" value="5" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                    <label  for="star5-'.$thePostID.'" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
                <input type="radio" id="star4-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="4" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                    <label  for="star4-'.$thePostID.'" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
                <input type="radio" id="star3-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="3" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                    <label  for="star3-'.$thePostID.'" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
                <input type="radio" id="star2-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="2" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                    <label for="star2-'.$thePostID.'" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
                <input type="radio" id="star1-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="1" data-id="'.$thePostID.'"  class="rating-star" />
                    <label for="star1-'.$thePostID.'" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
            </div>
        </p> 
        <p>
            <div id="services-name-'.$thePostID.'" class="services-btn">
            </div>
        </p>'
        ;

         return $content.$star;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wpa_rating_ad');
```

Answer (score 0):

you should customize the search.php in theme like below

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

                <?php
                    // Start the Loop.
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        $thePostID =get_the_ID(); 
                            $star='
                            <p>
                                <div class="rating">
                                    <legend>Please rate:</legend>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star5-'.$thePostID.'"  name="rating" value="5" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                                        <label  for="star5-'.$thePostID.'" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star4-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="4" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                                        <label  for="star4-'.$thePostID.'" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star3-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="3" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                                        <label  for="star3-'.$thePostID.'" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star2-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="2" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                                        <label for="star2-'.$thePostID.'" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="star1-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="1" data-id="'.$thePostID.'"  class="rating-star" />
                                        <label for="star1-'.$thePostID.'" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
                                </div>
                            </p> 
                            <p>
                                <div id="services-name-'.$thePostID.'" class="services-btn">
                                </div>
                            </p>'
                            ;

                             echo $content.$star;



                    endwhile;
                    // Previous/next post navigation.


                else :
                    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                endif;
            ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: i am creating a rating plugin if i have to customize search theme then whats the use of plugin